# Removing Unwanted Android apps

Tags: android

Google has downloaded several applications that I will never use and do not want.  They have used up almost all of my available phone memory.  How can I remove unwanted google apps from my phone?

Comment: Please hover over the tags in your question and **read** the summary.  "Unless the device docks with your computer, questions are better on android.stackexchange.com". Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer). See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try asking on http://android.stackexchange.com/ or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Agree this is an http://android.stackexchange.com/ question, but it is not likely to be migrated :-( or even well accepted there at that location, in the present form.  You will need to define the device you have? The available "application memory" ?  What exact "google" programs you wish to remove?  and what effort you made to remove  them via "apps" in settings, or via the store.  If you cover at least the minimum of expected information there, they will be (at least) able to make suggestions and assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps can be removed by uninstalling them through the Play Store. To do this:

1. Open the Play Store
2. Open the navigation sidebar using the menu button in the top left corner.
3. Tap "My Apps"
4. Scroll down the list to find an app you want to uninstall, and then tap it to view the app's details.
5. Tap the "Uninstall" button, and then tap "OK" to confirm.
6. The app will then be uninstalled.

Sometimes the app that you want to uninstall doesn't appear in the Play Store "My Apps" list. These apps can be uninstalled through Settings. The instructions vary based on which model of Android phone you have, and what version of Android you're using, but the steps are roughly as follows:

1. Open Settings
2. Scroll down and tap "Apps"
3. Scroll down the list to find the app you want to uninstall, and then tap it
4. Tap the "Uninstall" button and confirm that you want to uninstall it.
5. The app is now uninstalled.

Alternatively to step 4 some bloatware can't be uninstalled, however you can uninstall the updates then disable it. Although you may unexpectedly lose some functionality of other apps if you do this.

[image]

To uninstall these entirely you will need to root your phone, which is an advanced process and isn't recommended for most users.